# Git Credential Manager (GCM 2.2.2) yields `fatal: acces denied`, unable to authenticate with Git to GitHub on Windows 7

Tags: git, authentication, github, windows-7, git-credential-manager

I use Git and GitHub using the default Git Credential Manager (GCM) on my Windows 10 machine without any problems. Now, I installed Git with the same setup (all the **default** settings) on my 2 Windows 7 machines and git is working.

When I try to clone or push to any of my own *private* repositories I am asked by the GCM to authenticate (sign in with browser). Just **before** the browser opens I get a message in the CMD **`fatal: access denied`**. Then the browser opens with an authentication link as expected and immediately goes to a `127.0.0.1` (local?) address where I see **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** in Google Chrome.

The command prompt:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\Directory> git --version
git version 2.41.0.windows.3

C:\Users\<Username>\Directory> git credential-manager --version
2.2.2

C:\Users\<Username>\Directory> git config --global user.name <username of GitHub account>
C:\Users\<Username>\Directory> git config --global user.email <email of GitHub account>

C:\Users\<Username>\Directory> git clone https://github.com/<username>/<repository-name>.git
Cloning into '<repository-name>'...
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
:: until here everything was as expected ...
fatal: Access denied
:: AFTER the access denied message the browser opens and fails to load the page I expect
:: Then Git asks for username and password which were deprecated in August 2021 (It does not matter whether I try to log in using username and password or not)
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://github.com':
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<username>/<repository-name>.git'
```

Above I used `::` for comments which I added after I copied my CMD output. 
Git version 2.41.0.3 comes with **GCM 2.2.2**.

I tried this with Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge while logged in in GitHub and while not logged in. As well as in a guest window in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. All with the same result.

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows/c/kgmtXGQFj4M?pli=1) Windows 7 should still be supported, but cloning a repository or pushing to the remote is impossible. I have no problems when running this on my Windows 10 machine.

See **[GitHub Git Ecosystem - Git Credential Manager issue](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/issues/1365)** with full logs using `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GCM_TRACE=1`.

*ChatGPT did not yield any useful results.*